# How to get the transcription from the custom commands in Houndify

Tags: houndify

How to get the transcription from custom commands irrespective of users saying in houndify ?
Created a custom command
ClientMatch : i have an expression "can i get".("apple" | "mango")
User : can i get pineapple
Houndify should detect Transcription: can i get apple (Since expression has only two options pineapple word is somewhat related to apple)
Present Houndify detecting Transcription as " Can i get pineappple"

How can get the transcription only from custom commands?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Custom commands help enhance the understanding of your product, but you cannot force it to only match one of your options.  If it doesn’t match, like in your case of pineapple, you’ll receive a NoResultCommand and the transcription.